# GUNICORN FastAPI Deployment with Proxy

Tags: python, nginx, fastapi, gunicorn

I am currently setting up a FastAPI application to run on an AWS RockyLinux 8 instance with a [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) deployment. Most of the documentation that I have read recommends NGINX as a proxy server.

I currently have an Apache sever running on this instance and would rather not install another HTTP daemon if I can help it.

My question is: Why is a proxy HTTP server needed at all? **gunicorn** seems to run just fine without a proxy HTTP server simply by specifying a port other than 80. Is this a security recommendation or am I missing something?

Comment: A proxy server lessens network traffic by rejecting unwanted requests, forwarding requests to balance and optimize server workload, and fulfilling requests by serving data from cache rather than unnecessarily contacting the true destination server. Ref IBM

Comment: That makes sense ... thank you.  How a proxy detects "unwanted requests" is interesting and probably merits it's own question,

Comment: We can allow/block the requests which are mapped to our locations only.